# Global sections and divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties

I'm trying to understand the proof of the Theorem at page 163 from [Mumford, Abelian Varieties](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~pavel/cmi/References/Mumford_Abelian_Varities.pdf), and I have a question about one step. 
This is the situation:

$X$ is an abelian variety (hence there's the correspondence between line bundles, Cartier divisors and Weil divisors), $\mathcal{L}$ is an ample line bundle on $X$ and Mumford shows that we can take an effective divisor $D$ without multiple components such that $\mathcal{L}\cong\mathcal{O}_X(D)$. We want to show that $\mathcal{L}^3$ is very ample, hence that:

(1) Given $x_0, x_1\in X$, $x_0\neq x_1$, there exists $D' \in |3D|$ such that $x_0\in Supp D'$, $x_1\notin Supp D'$.

(2) Given any tangent vector $t$ to $X$ at $x_0$, there exists $D'\in|3D|$ such that $x_0\in Supp D'$ and $t$ is not tangential to $D'$.

In the proof of the point (1) above, we suppose that (1) is not true (without loss of generality for $x_0=0$) so we want to arrive to a contradiciton. With this hypothesis, one has that $t_{x_1}^*(D)=D$ where $t_{x_1}:X\rightarrow X, y\mapsto y+x_1$ is the translation morphism. Hence $x_1\in K(\mathcal{L})=\{ x\in X: t_x^*\mathcal{L}\cong \mathcal{L}\}$ which is a finite group for $\mathcal{L}$ ample. Hence $x_1$ generates a finite subgroup of $X$, which we call $F$. We consider then the étale morphism $\pi:X\rightarrow X/F$ (see costruction of $(X/F, \pi)$ from page 66 to page 69). Now, $D_1=\pi(Supp F)$ is a closed subset of pure codimension one in $X/F$, so we can see it as a divisor with all components of multiplicity one; the same holds for $\pi^*(D)$ and Mumford shows that $D=\pi^*(D_1)$, so $\mathcal{L}\cong \pi^*(\mathcal{O}_{X/F}(D_1))$, and that $\dim\Gamma(\mathcal{L})>\dim\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_{X/F}(D_1))$. Then, Mumford says:

> Since the set of all divisors $D_1$ such that $\mathcal{L}\cong\pi^*(\mathcal{O}_{X/F}(D_1))$ fall into a finite set of equivalence classes, this proves that all sections $s\in\Gamma(L)$ either define multiple divisors, or lie into one of a finite number of lower-dimensional subspaces $\pi^*\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_{X/F}(D_1))$. This is a contradiction.

I don't understand this conclusion. Can someone explain it to me?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you agree that the set of $D_1$ is finite in this way?

Comment: I can't see it. But I don't understand the rest anyway.

Comment: Well maybe we should start there. Is there a relationship between the Picard groups of $X$ and $X/F$?

Comment: The only thing I found is here: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.114.2496&rep=rep1&type=pdf in section 4, Picard Group of quotients.

Comment: I _think_ Mumford spells this out in the section on finite group quotients: there's an exact sequence $0 \to \hat{F} \to \operatorname{Pic}(X/F) \to \operatorname{Pic} X$. I think this takes care of the first part. Now one needs to argue that a general section of $\mathcal{L}$ can't have multiple components. This seems like it should be true but I don't see it as obvious from what he says.

Comment: What do you mean with "multiple components" of a general section?

Comment: "multiple divisors", in your last quote.

Comment: And what does Mumford mean with "all sections define multiple divisors"?

Comment: I would say that $\sum n_iD_i$ is _multiple_ if some $n_i \neq 0,1$.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. And what is the divisor "defined" by a global section in this case? Is he talking about the divisors $D_1$ such that $\mathcal{L}\cong\pi^*(\mathcal{O}_{X/F}(D_1))$? If this is the case, we already showed in the previous part of the proof that $D_1$ has no multiple components.

Comment: Sorry, ignore the previous comment. I think I understand a bit more now. We know that, if for a line bundle we have that $\dim H^0(X,\mathcal{L})>0$, then $\mathcal{L}\cong \mathcal{O}_X(D)$ for some effective divisor $D$. You can see this result in Hartshorne, page 157, and it's true for $D$ Cartier divisor so in this case also for $D$ Weil divisor - which is Mumford's point of view. In this particular case, we show that we can take $D$ such that $D$ has no multiple components. So this is why it can't be true that "ALL global sections define multiple divisors". Do you agree?

Comment: So maybe the quote means: since such a $D$ always exists, we always have this $D_1$, but then we get a contradiction from the fact that $\dim \Gamma(\mathcal{L})>\dim \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_{X/F}(D_1))$. Right? And if this is the case one needs to understand the last sentence now. Is he saying that $\dim \Gamma(\mathcal{L})=\dim \pi^*\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_{X/F}(D_1))=\dim \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_{X/F}(D_1))$?